# Get list order after dragging and dropping list items asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got the following code that allows drag and drop of list items:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <style>
        header, section {
            display: block;
        }
        body {
            font-family: 'Droid Serif';
        }
        h1, h2 {
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        #features {
            margin: auto;
            width: 460px;
            font-size: 0.9em;
        }
        .connected, .sortable, .exclude, .handles {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 0;
            width: 310px;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .sortable.grid {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .connected li, .sortable li, .exclude li, .handles li {
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            background: #F6F6F6;
            font-family: "Tahoma";
            color: #1C94C4;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 22px;
        }
        .handles span {
            cursor: move;
        }
        li.disabled {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        .sortable.grid li {
            line-height: 80px;
            float: left;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        li.highlight {
            background: #FEE25F;
        }
        #connected {
            width: 440px;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .connected {
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
        }
        .connected.no2 {
            float: right;
        }
        li.sortable-placeholder {
            border: 1px dashed #CCC;
            background: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <section>
        <h2>Sortable List</h2>
        <ul class="sortable list">
            <li><asp:Label ID="lblRouting1" runat="server" Text="Routing 1"></asp:Label></li>
            <li> <asp:Label ID="lblRouting2" runat="server" Text="Routing 2"></asp:Label></li>
            <li> <asp:Label ID="lblRouting3" runat="server" Text="Routing 3"></asp:Label></li>
            <li> <asp:Label ID="lblRouting4" runat="server" Text="Routing 4"></asp:Label></li>
            <li> <asp:Label ID="lblRouting5" runat="server" Text="Routing 5"></asp:Label></li>
            <li> <asp:Label ID="lblRouting6" runat="server" Text="Routing 6"></asp:Label></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    </div>
    </form>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.sortable.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('.sortable').sortable();
                $('.handles').sortable({
                    handle: 'span'
                });
                $('.connected').sortable({
                    connectWith: '.connected'
                });
                $('.exclude').sortable({
                    items: ':not(.disabled)'
                });
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It allows the user to drag the list items to the order that they require it. I'm trying to find out if there's a way in c# that you can get the order of the li when the user has changed the order please?

Comment: you have to submit the new order back to the server, or each time the user changes the order, submit the change to the server using ajax.

Comment: Hi Banana, sorry how do I go about doing that please?

Comment: i will write an example for you in a while, if you are willing to wait

Comment: Yeah, that'll be great thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you want, would be to submit a change the user does, back to serverside using ajax.

**----------------------**

**JavaScript Part:**

**----------------------**

in your `.sortable()` initialization, you need to add a **stop** handler that will fire when you drop the dragged item. the following code alerts the new position of the dropped element:

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        alert("New position: " + ui.item.index()); 
    }
});
```

now that we have the new position of the dragged element, you need to submit it back to the server.

we do it by sending 2 arguments to the server:

- a unique ID to identify the element (could be a pre-set custom attribute that you assign to the element)
- the new position

to submit details back to the server, we will use ajax. first, we declare a var with the options for the ajax:

```
$(function () {
     $('.sortable').sortable({
         stop: function (event, ui) {
             var ID_To_Submit = ui.item.attr("myCustomIDAtribute");
             var New_Position = ui.item.index();
             var options = {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "./myWebPage.aspx/myWebMethod",
                 data: JSON.stringify({
                     ID: ID_To_Submit,
                     POS: New_Position
                 }),
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (response) {

                 }
             };

             //and then, we submit the ajax with the options:
             $.ajax(options);
         }
     });
 });
```

**explanation:**

- assuming we set a custom attribute to our `<li myCustomIDAtribute="12">` element, 
  this is how we retrieve it  
  `var ID_To_Submit = ui.item.attr("myCustomIDAtribute");`
- this will obviously get the new position: 
  `var New_Position = ui.item.index();`
- here you specify the path to your aspx page where the webmethod that will receive the
   ajax is located, and the name of the method:
  `url: "./myWebPage.aspx/myWebMethod",`
- this one is tricky, here you specify the name of the arguments in the webmethod **on server side**, and what they will receive. here the argument names on server side will be `ID` and `POS`, and they will receive the value of the javascript vars `ID_To_Submit` and `New_Position` accordingly.
  `data: JSON.stringify({ID:ID_To_Submit,POS:New_Position}),`

  **remember to stringify them using json, as we are sending it in a json string.**
- the `success: function (response) {}` is a callback function that fires when the server returns from the web method. usually the return value is placed directly in `response` argument, but in ASP.NET it is located in `response.d`

**----------------------**

**C# Part:**

**----------------------**

in your **myWebPage.aspx** page, in the code behind, you will create a web method that will receive ajax posts:

you will need to declare it as a `[WebMethod]`

```
[WebMethod]
public static string myWebMethod(ID,POS)
{
    //do what you need with the ID and the new POS
    if(/*everything updated fine*/)
    {
        return "changed";
    }
    else
    {
        return "failed";
    }
}
```

- note: you can return whatever object you want, just parse it  on javascript side correctly.

**------------------------------**

**Back to JavaScript Part:**

**------------------------------**

remember the ajax's success function? the return value will be placed in `response.d`

 remember how we returned a string `"changed"` or `"failed"`?

```
var options = {
     // ...
     // all the options
     //...
     success: function (response) {
         if (response.d == "changed") {
             //position updated on server successfully
         } else if (response.d == "failed") {
             //did not update on server successfully
         }
     }
 };
```

Thats about it. if you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: oops i forgot to mention that the ajax part you call from inside the **stop** handler. i've updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Banana thank you so much for your help. I've done that but it's coming out with an error I'm afraid. Error details: Unhandled exception at line 46, column 4 in http://localhost:51364/jquery.sortable.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'removeClass' of undefined or null reference. It's on the line within the jquery.sortable.js on: dragging.removeClass('sortable-dragging').show();

Comment: Try first to create a project on a smaller scale, create an empty project and just add the code from my example. When you get it to work, try adding more code blocks from your main project. If you get any errors along the way, please post here and we'll try to solve those :)

Comment: I've started a new project and added your code. The drag and drop works great but it doesn't call the webmethod. I've tried putting a breakpoint in but doesn't break. I presume the webmethod goes on the .cs of the webpage ie: public partial class myWebPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string myWebMethod(string ID, int Pos)
    {
        ////do what you need with the ID and the new POS
        //if(/*everything updated fine*/)
        //{
            return "changed";
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    return "failed";
        //}
    }
}

Comment: Yes it does in there. In your javascript, put an alert after $.ajax(options) and see if it gets called

Comment: I've made a fiddle. The html part has all the aspx code and the box below has the aspx.cs code. not quite in the fiddle format but at least I can show my code lol. http://jsfiddle.net/tj8vjqdm/1/ .I've put the alert in but it doesn't show. Many thanks for your help Banana it's much appreciated.

Comment: you have a redundant `success` block outside of the rest of your code which prevents the javascript from executing in the fiddle you showed me, i cleaned the fiddle for testing purposes and when removing the extra `success` block it runs fine: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/tj8vjqdm/2/). check your code, insert `console.log("test 1/2/3")` in between major code blocks (**but not inside the options block**) and let me know where your code stops running

Comment: that success block with the condition should replace the success block inside the `var options ={}` above. i have updated my answer to make it a bit clearer

Comment: yay.. that bit of code works now and it runs the script and the alert comes up (I'm here) but it's still not breaking on the webmethod. nearly there lol.

Comment: great :) next step is to verify that the `url:` part in the options is correct.

Comment: Right.. My aspx page is myWebPage.aspx that contains all the html and js code and a myWebPage.aspx.cs code behind with a webmethod of: public static string myWebMethod(string ID, int Pos). They're not contained within any folders but in the root of the project. oooo... on another note above. One of the reasons why it wasn't working was due to using an older version of jquery...

Comment: note that the ajax data argument names are case sensitive and must match the ones from the web method. if the web method's argument is named `int Pos` then it should be `Pos` in the ajax part as well. and if its `int POS`, then in ajax it should be `POS` too.

Comment: Another note: create an override to the webmethod which doesnt accept arguments. if there is a problem with the ajax's data part, it will call the webmethod which doesnt have arguments at all.

Comment: Welldone that man. Thank you for all your help. I understand jQueryu alot better now with webmethods ;-)